# Is there any different between these 2 command?

Tags: unity, c#

I came across this question on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147553/int-num-new-int-what-happens-when-this-line-executes . Wonder if there is any difference for sprite and spriteRender in unity between both of these commands `sprite y=new sprite()` and `sprite y;` or `SpriteRenderer x=new SpriteRenderer()` and `SpriteRenderer x;`? I tested in unity, both commands also generate the same option to attach game object, so do both have the same meaning as well?

Comment: Following the standard rules for [tag:C#], `Sprite` and `SpriteRenderer` are [reference types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types). That means that `Sprite y;` or `SpriteRenderer x;` initialize the value of `y` and `x` respectively to `null`. `Sprite y = new Sprite();` is not valid, because `Sprite` does not have a public constructor - you can create them via the static factory method `Sprite.Create(...)` though. Since this is standard C# syntax, it's not game-development specific, and you can find Q&A about it on StackOverflow instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unity components can't be created with `new`, so such command as `SpriteRenderer x = new SpriteRenderer();` must be avoided. In this particular case you will get `x` initialzied with `null`.

And input box for attaching gameObject is generated for every `public` component in class.